# Angular ngOptions list blank after selecting something

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

My basic setup is Nodejs, MongoDB, and Angular. I am using ngOptions to make a dropdown list pulled from the DB and showing the data for the selection below that.

Everything works fine when the page loads. The list is populated and when I select something the values for my selection are displayed. But after I make the selection, the options list is no longer populated. I'm still a bit new to Node and Angular and am probably overlooking something, but I can't figure out what.

Here is the controller and factory I'm using:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
     .factory('Users', ['$http', function($http) {
        return $http.get('/users');
     }])
     .controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'Users', function($scope, Users) {
        Users.success(function(data) {
            $scope.users = data;
        }).error(function(data, error) {
            console.log(error);
            $scope.users = [];
        });
     }])
```

Here is the page code I'm using:

```
      <div ng-controller="UserController">
      <span  class="nullable">
        <select ng-model="users" ng-options="user.name for user in users">
            <option value="">--choose user--</option>
        </select>
    </span>
  <br/>
    <ul>
      <li>Name: {{users.name}}</li>
      <li>EID: {{users.emp_id}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ng-model is bound to $scope.users, so when you select a user, $scope.users is set to that user, replacing the array of users returned by your User service.  Since user is not an array, ng-options doesn't know what to display, so it displays nothing.

You probably want

```
<select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="user.name for user in users">
    <option value="">--choose user--</option>
</select>
```

$scope.selectedUser will contain the selected user after you select one.

As an aside, if you want to pre-select one of the users (i.e, the first user, for example, you could modify your controller in this way:

```
 controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'Users', function($scope, Users) {
    Users.success(function(data) {
        $scope.users = data;
        if($scope.users.length > 0) {
            $scope.selectedUser = $scope.users[0];
        }
    }).error(function(data, error) {
        console.log(error);
        $scope.users = [];
    });
 }])
```